# R Matching String to String per row per column

Tags: r

I need to return True or False per row for a text dataset like the following:

```
 df<-data.frame(c("blue","green","red"),c("red","green","blue"))
 names(df)<-c("df.x","df.y")
df

   df.x  df.y
1  blue   red
2 green green
3   red  blue
```

The result needs to be True or False and added to the data.frame. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `df$ans <-ifelse(df.x==df.y, TRUE, FASLE)`

Comment: What is the condition you want to be TRUE or FALSE? You should show what you want your expected output to be.

Comment: You can try Reduce(‘==‘,df)

Comment: seriously just do `df$new <- df$df.x == df$df.y`, there's absolutely no point to try to be clever here, `do.call` and `Reduce` cannot be generalizabe to more than 2 columns so no point, `within` is adding characters and impairing readibility and using `dplyr` for this is totally overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(df.equal = ifelse(x == y, "True", "False"))
```

Depending on whether you want to use that data as a boolean later on, you could also use...

```
df <- df %>% mutate(df.equal = ifelse(x == y, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Comment: `ifelse(x == y, TRUE, FALSE)` is the same as `x == y`

Answer (score 0):

Using base `R` and `within`:

```
df <- within(df, {
  df.z = df.x == df.y
})
df
```

This yields

```
   df.x  df.y  df.z
1  blue   red FALSE
2 green green  TRUE
3   red  blue FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can use `do.call` with `==`

```
df$df.z <-  do.call(`==`, df)
df$df.z
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```